# Show that the set $A=\{(x,y):4\le x\le 5 \wedge y=1\}$ is compact in the Euclidean metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

Let $(\Bbb R^2, d)$ be a Euclidean metric space. Show, using definition of compactness, that the set
$$A=\{(x,y):4\le x\le 5 \wedge y=1\}$$
is compact.

**Attempt:**
For simplify, write $A=B \times C$, where $B=[4,5]$ and $C=\{1\}$.
Notice that $B$ and $C$ both are compact.

Let $\mathcal{G}=\{G_{a}:a \in I\}$ be arbitrary open cover of $B \times C$. Take any $(x,y) \in B \times C$. Then there exists $a_{(x,y)} \in I$ such that $(x,y) \in G_{a_{(x,y)}}$.
Since $G_{a_{(x,y)}}$ is open, there exists a neighborhood $U_y(x)$ of $x$ and a neighborhood $V_x(y)$ of $y$ such that
$$(x,y) \in U_y(x) \times V_x(y) \subseteq G_{a_{(x,y)}}.$$
Notice that for any $x \in B$, we have
$$C \subseteq \bigcup_{y \in \{1\}} V_x(y)=V_x(1).$$
Since $C$ is compact, there exists $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_M \in C$ such that
$$C \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^M V_x(y_k) = V_x(1).$$
Next, define
$$U(x):=\bigcap_{k=1}^M U_{y_k}(x) \subseteq B.$$
We have
$$U(x) \times C \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^M U_{y_k}(x) \times V_x(y_k).$$
Now, notice that $\{U(x):x \in B\}$ is an open cover of $B$. Since $B$ is compact, there exists $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N$ such that
$$B \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^N U(x_j).$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
B \times C \subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^N U(x_j) \times C &\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^N \bigcup_{k=1}^M U_{y_k}(x_j) \times V_{x_j}(y_k) \\
&\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^N \bigcup_{k=1}^M G_{a_(x_j,y_k)}.
\end{align*}
Thus, $A$ is compact.

I'm still in doubt.
Does this approach correct? Does there exists a 'simple' approach to solve this problem?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A,B$ be compact and let $\bigcup_{i\in I}Z_i$ be a open cover of $A\times B$ and write $Z_i=X_i\times Y_i$.

Then $\bigcup X_i$ and $\bigcup Y_i$ are open covers for $A$ and $B$ respectively so that there exists finite sets $J_A,J_B\subset I$ with
$$A\subset\bigcup_{i\in  J_A}X_i, \ B\subset\bigcup_{i\in J_B}Y_i
\implies A\times B\subset \bigcup_{i\in J_A, J_B}Z_i$$